# Unable to connect to publicly accessible redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**I have 2 clusters,both publicly accessible,same security groups,but in different public subnets,I can connect to one cluster from local, but not the other.
Tried connecting via cluster ip, tried adding my ip as well as 0.0.0.0/0 to security groups, rebooted cluster after allowing public access, nothing helped.**

Comment: Show route table for both public subnets. Maybe one public subnet has igw attached and the other no.

Comment: Please post a solution as Proposed answer, and remove from Question, to make it QnA style

Answer (score 1):

When configuring cluster, I get to select the subnet group, and I chose the default one, which was a mixture of public and private subnets. So AWS randomly chose a subnet from it for my cluster, which was a private one. that is why I haven't been able to connect to it via local.So I just had to create anew subnet group with only public subnets, and use this subnet group while creating an entirely newly cluster, as doing subnet modifications to a cluster ain't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the associated subnets have proper route tables directing traffic to the internet gateway, and that the security group allows inbound connections from your IP or 0.0.0.0/0. Check the cluster's configuration to confirm it's using the correct public subnets and that network interfaces are attached properly. Verify route tables and internet gateway settings for the VPC, and ensure DNS resolution is enabled

Comment: 2 clusters use same vpc thats public, still, i can access only one of them locally.

Comment: Creating a subnet group consisting of only public subnets helped, Thanks.